# Model Examples always with 1 or 2 features

Tags: pca, feature-selection, feature-engineering, isolation-forest

Why are all the model examples that I see on sklearn (e.g., https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.LocalOutlierFactor.html or https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_isolation_forest.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-isolation-forest-py).

Would it be reasonable to expect that most ML applications are going to have at least a few more features to consider?

Am I missing some point like doing PCA to reduce the features fitting the model?  Thats the only explanation I can come up with - in my naive mind.

Comment: They are tiny examples meant to run quickly and show you how to write code that compiles, not indications of what the machine learning world finds interesting.

Comment: Thanks - I still cant seem to find any isolation forest examples with a handful or more features (continuous and categorical) that provides some good theories / practices in appropriate transformations of variables that leads to some effective plots, for example.